# Can plotly return a list of existing figures for an account?

Tags: python, plotly

When appending data to a plotly chart it appears that the chart filename must exist to add data to it.
Is there a way for a given account to return a list of existing filenames so I can create them if they don't exist or append to them if they do ?

Answer (score 2):

`fileopt='append'` will create a new file if it doesn't already exist, so in many cases you can use that:

```
# Will create "kitten plot" if it doesn't already exist, or append
# "data" if it does:
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='kitten plot', fileopt='append')
```

However, if you really need `fileopt='extend'`, you can get a listing of your files using our new API, version 2.  Unfortunately we have not yet added support for this API to the Python library, but you can make a GET request to: https://api.plot.ly/v2/files and it will return a JSON dictionary of all your files.  Full documentation on the API is available starting at https://api.plot.ly/v2.  We are working towards supporting all operations from this new API, and of course direct support will be added to all our API libraries.

Also note that by default, accessing an API v2 URL from your browser will give you full documentation and a formatted version of the response.  If you access the URL from a library such as Python's requests library, you'll get a JSON response by default.  You can append ?format=json to the URL to get a JSON response in your browser.

Comment: ok, the trouble with append is that it doubles up my traces (which is what the doco said thus I didn't try it. An 'extend' fileopt that created non existent charts would be very handy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do.  If the file does not exist: create it and add the traces.  If the file does exist: do nothing?  I'm confused.

Comment: ok, sorry, I'll try to make it clearer. 'append' is great if the plot doesn't exist as it creates them (with trace1, trace2, trace3 and trace4). The downside is, if the plot filename already exists I end up with trace1, trace2, trace3 and trace4 stopping and traces5-8 appearing (which is exactly what the doco says btw so no complaints there). The 'extend' option is great in that it keeps adding to existing traces (so I don't end up with traces5-8 above. The catch is, if the filename doesn't already exist it throws an error (i.e. doesn't create a new plot from scratch)

Comment: OK, I understand what you're trying to do now, and you can do it with our just-released version 2 API.